# What is the history behind Scotty's hidden freezer and bottle of Scotch?

Tags: props, star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series

In the ***Star Trek*** TOS Episode s2e21 *"By Any Other Name"*, there are some scenes involving Montgomery Scott attempting to get an alien drunk. Part of the gag has him pulling out a bottle of Scotch Whisky from its hiding place. The bottle is something Scotty really wanted to save, and it's not just hidden, but hidden in a medieval knight's helm **and freezing, with frost on it and steam/vapor coming off from it.**

[image]

How did this come about in production? What was so special about this bottle? What was Scotty saving it for? Specifically how did the freezer part get thought up? Was this ever referenced again?

Answer (score 3):

> It's verra, verra, verra old scotch whisky.

Are you sure it's frost and not dust? I know they're not likely to have a lot of dust on the Enterprise, but if it was dusty when he acquired it, maybe he didn't bother wiping it off.

He's likely just hiding it because it's old, and therefore valuable, and he didn't want anyone stealing it from his quarters.

You can watch the scene [here](https://youtu.be/FWEDZFoLmyA).

Memory Alpha has a photo of just the bottle, but I can't make out the brand (if it's even a real brand).

[image: By Any Other Name Scotch]

Comment: I thought that there were no money in ST universe: what does *valuable* mean in this context?

Comment: A real whisky drinker would tell you that you do not chill whisky as it kills the flavour, and Scotty as a 'real' Scotsman would know this. I also think that in the era of Classic Star Trek some currency exchange was used, for example Harry Mudd from 'Mudds Women' was a trader that implies an economy of some sort.

Comment: @mattiav27 Perhaps "special" would have been a better word, but there are more types of value than just monetary.

Comment: It's definitely dust.

@mattiav27 - something can be rare or precious without having specific monetary value.

Comment: Yeah, here's a video of that whole drinking scene.  When he pulls the bottle out of the helmet, he blows dust off of it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZGuvyM8C88

Comment: Yes it is dust, on a rewatch. I'm leaving the question as is because of first impressions.

Comment: If I recall the bottle merely stands behind the helmet assembly. It is hardly held within it. Watch closely once he picks it up. Plenty good for a passing prop on a TV show. Great scene.